# RxJS get the latest value from an inner observable and compare with outer observable

Tags: rxjs

In my example I have an input field that I want to sync with an object:

- If the user types something in the input the value of the object should be updated.
- If the object changes from an external source I want to reflect this value in the input.

I've tried to use `withLatestFrom` operator, but it doesn't work as I would expect.
Here is a StackBlitz [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-hbetvg?file=index.ts) where I reproduced this example.

If you press the key `p` for example in the input, there will be no output to the console, but the `name$` stream has already output a value. Here I was expecting to see the message

```bash
newVal: m --- oldVal: m
```

If you press another key, for example `e`, you will see in the console:

```bash
newVal: me --- oldVal: m
```

but I was expecting to see

```bash
newVal: me --- oldVal: me
```

Maybe I get it wrong, but from my understanding I expected `withLatestFrom` to simply get the most recent emission of the observable.
But it seems that it's with one value behind.

**P.S** This example is trivial and is used to simplify the real scenario. The data structures are the same. The idea is that every time a main observable emits, `user$`, in my case, I want to compare that value to the most recent value of stream `name$`.

Maybe the `withLatestFrom` is not the correct approach, so I would be open to other suggestions.

Comment: It seems to me that your description is inconsistent with how the StackBlitz app behaves.  For instance, if I press `p`, both `newVal` and `oldVar` are the same. And they are still the same if I then press `e`.

Answer (score 0):

I think [pairwise](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/pairwise) might help you there:

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input')!;
const button = document.querySelector('button')!;
    
fromEvent<InputEvent>(button, 'click')
    .subscribe(() => {
        input.value = 'John Doe';
        input.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
    });
    
fromEvent<InputEvent>(input, 'input')
    .pipe(
        map(() => input.value),
        startWith(''),
        pairwise()
    )
    .subscribe(([vOld, vNew]) =>
        console.log(`newVal: ${vNew} --- oldVal: ${vOld}`)
    );
```